# Spark - Sum of row values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following DataFrame:

```
January | February | March
-----------------------------
  10    |    10    |  10
  20    |    20    |  20
  50    |    50    |  50
```

I'm trying to add a column to this which is the sum of the values of each row.

```
January | February | March  | TOTAL
----------------------------------
  10    |    10    |   10   |  30
  20    |    20    |   20   |  60
  50    |    50    |   50   |  150
```

As far as I can see, all the built in aggregate functions seem to be for calculating values in single columns. How do I go about using values across columns on a per row basis (using Scala)?

I've gotten as far as

```
val newDf: DataFrame = df.select(colsToSum.map(col):_*).foreach ...
```

Comment: What is colsToSum? Maybe List[Column] ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You were very close with this:

```
val newDf: DataFrame = df.select(colsToSum.map(col):_*).foreach ...
```

Instead, try this:

```
val newDf = df.select(colsToSum.map(col).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2) as "sum")
```

I think this is the best of the the answers, because it is as fast as the answer with the hard-coded SQL query, and as convenient as the one that uses the `UDF`. It's the best of both worlds -- and I didn't even add a full line of code!

Comment: Hi David, is there a similar way to find the minimum instead the sum?

Comment: This is off the top of my head, and I haven't touched spark in about 6 months, but try something like changing: `(c1, c2) => c1 + c2` to `(c1, c2) => if (c1 < c2) c1; else c2`

Comment: Thanks Daivd, I have tried this solution and it didn't work

Comment: I have similar scenario but I have more than 300 columns to sum, I tried the solution but it failed due to max iteration exceed, any suggestion ?

Comment: Hello David, what does the `col` variable stands for ? And what is the type of colsToSum, a list  of strings ?

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively and using Hugo's approach and example, you can create a `UDF` that receives any quantity of columns and `sum` them all.

```py
from functools import reduce

def superSum(*cols):
   return reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, cols)

add = udf(superSum)

df.withColumn('total', add(*[df[x] for x in df.columns])).show()


+-------+--------+-----+-----+
|January|February|March|total|
+-------+--------+-----+-----+
|     10|      10|   10|   30|
|     20|      20|   20|   60|
+-------+--------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 8):

This code is in Python, but it can be easily translated:

```py
# First we create a RDD in order to create a dataFrame:
rdd = sc.parallelize([(10, 10,10), (20, 20,20)])
df = rdd.toDF(['January', 'February', 'March'])
df.show()

# Here, we create a new column called 'TOTAL' which has results
# from add operation of columns df.January, df.February and df.March

df.withColumn('TOTAL', df.January + df.February + df.March).show()
```

Output:

```py
+-------+--------+-----+
|January|February|March|
+-------+--------+-----+
|     10|      10|   10|
|     20|      20|   20|
+-------+--------+-----+

+-------+--------+-----+-----+
|January|February|March|TOTAL|
+-------+--------+-----+-----+
|     10|      10|   10|   30|
|     20|      20|   20|   60|
+-------+--------+-----+-----+
```

You can also create an User Defined Function it you want, here a link of Spark documentation:
[UserDefinedFunction (udf)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction)

Answer (score 6):

Working Scala example with dynamic column selection:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((10, 10, 10), (20, 20, 20)))
val df = rdd.toDF("January", "February", "March")
df.show()

+-------+--------+-----+
|January|February|March|
+-------+--------+-----+
|     10|      10|   10|
|     20|      20|   20|
+-------+--------+-----+

val sumDF = df.withColumn("TOTAL", df.columns.map(c => col(c)).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2))
sumDF.show()

+-------+--------+-----+-----+
|January|February|March|TOTAL|
+-------+--------+-----+-----+
|     10|      10|   10|   30|
|     20|      20|   20|   60|
+-------+--------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically not across the columns but down the rows? Meaning, without resorting to typing in `spark.sql("select sum(col1), sum(col1) from df")`, can we sum the other way (down the columns, not across) with just as a concise of statement?

Comment: `df.select(df.columns.map(c => sum(col(c))) :_*)` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use expr() for this.In scala use

```
df.withColumn("TOTAL", expr("January+February+March"))
```

Comment: how does `expr()` of sums handle nulls among the elements?

Comment: If any element of the sum is null will return null. For example: 1+0+null  returns NULL