# Calculate row mean, ignoring NAs in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, aggregation

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the mean of **rows** in a Spark Dataframe in Scala where I want to ignore NAs. In R, there is a very convenient function called rowMeans where one can specify to ignore NAs:

```
rowmeans(df,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I'm unable to find a corresponding function for Spark Dataframes, and I wonder if anyone has a suggestion or input if this would be possible. Replacing them with 0 won't due since this will affect the denominator.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360540/spark-sum-of-row-values), however my dataframe will have hundreds of columns.

Any help and shared insights is appreciated, cheers!

Comment: [Spark Scala row-wise average by handling null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53189965/6910411)

Answer (score 0):

Usually such functions ignore nulls by default. 
Even if there are some mixed columns with numeric and string types, this one will drop strings and nulls, and calculate only numerics.

```
df.select(df.columns.map(c => mean(col(c))) :_*).show
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I'm looking for a way to compute the mean of the rows in a dataframe.

Comment: Sry, I confused rows with columns. Then for rows it is also easy. First we fill nulls with 0, then compute columns of means.
val df_filled = df.na.fill("0");

val nrow = n;

val sumDF = df_filled.withColumn("TOTAL", df_filled.columns.map(c => col(c)).reduce((c1, c2) => (c1 + c2)/nrow));

sumDF.show()

Comment: Hi, yes that will work but then again as I stated; if we fill NAs with zeros, this will affect the denominator making the computed means biased, if I assume that is how it will be computed. And as in my case, I will have around 1500 columns that I want to sum, making it quite impossible to say which columns to sum with a reduce statement. So in conclusion, I need to sum rows and compute mean where NAs are not taking into consideration for a large number of columns. Simple thing, but at the same time not..

Comment: Right. I guess iteratively collect to R and compute rowmeans of each batch will be faster than try to find out direct way to do it on scala.

Comment: Yes, probably. However I'm not sure how to accomplish that so I might need to skip this step completely in my data processing..

Comment: why not ? you simply execute collect(df) and your spark DafaFrame becomes R data.frame

Comment: Yes, but I cannot call R functions from within the Scala code, right? Or how do you mean? I'm running a large data processing step on a remote cluster, and I will not have time to look into how to set up a hybrid solution that uses Scala and R. I'm conducting my master thesis so I'm quite time limited.. :(

Comment: I ran your command for columns `df.select(df.columns.map(c => mean(col(c))) :_*).show`, and the column with `NaN` values came out to have a mean of `NaN`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by first identifying which fields are numeric, and then selecting their mean for each row...

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = List(("a",1,2,3.0),("b",5,6,7.0)).toDF("s1","i1","i2","i3")

// grab numeric fields
val numericFields = df.schema.fields.filter(f => f.dataType==IntegerType || f.dataType==LongType || f.dataType==FloatType || f.dataType==DoubleType || f.dataType==ShortType).map(_.name)

// compute mean
val rowMeans = df.select(numericFields.map(f => col(f)).reduce(_+_) / lit(numericFields.length) as "row_mean")

rowMeans.show
```