# Apply function on all rows of dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I want to apply a function on all rows of DataFrame. 
Example:

```
|A  |B   |C   |
|1  |3   |5   |
|6  |2   |0   |
|8  |2   |7   |
|0  |9   |4   |


Myfunction(df)

Myfunction(df: DataFrame):{
//Apply sum of columns on each row
}
```

Wanted output:

```
1+3+5 = 9
6+2+0 = 8
...
```

How can that be done is Scala please? i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243744/get-specific-row-from-spark-dataframe) but got no luck.

Comment: Can you please share the output/expected dataframe as well?

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: @AbderrahmenM Edited my answer as per you requested but i would still recommend to use the first approach(by creating a new column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You don't need to write any function for this, all you can do is to create a new column by summing up all the columns you want.

```
scala> df.show
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  1|  2|  4|
|  1|  2|  5|
+---+---+---+


scala> df.withColumn("sum",col("A")+col("B")+col("C")).show
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|sum|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  6|
|  1|  2|  4|  7|
|  1|  2|  5|  8|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Edited:

Well you can run `map` function on each row and get the sum using row index/field name.

```
scala> df.map(x=>x.getInt(0) + x.getInt(1) + x.getInt(2)).toDF("sum").show
+---+
|sum|
+---+
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
+---+


scala> df.map(x=>x.getInt(x.fieldIndex("A")) + x.getInt(x.fieldIndex("B")) + x.getInt(x.fieldIndex("C"))).toDF("sum").show
+---+
|sum|
+---+
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
+---+
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted by this question to know how to 'parse' a DF row by row

Comment: @Goldie You should not use `fieldIndex` but `getInt` with index. If you really want to access using names, just combine like `x.getInt(x.fieldIndex("A"))`

Comment: @Rafaël  Dummy me ! Thanks for pointing this out. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Goldie No worries ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#map(scala.Function1,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) is the solution if you want to apply a function to every row of a dataframe. For every Row, you can return a tuple and a new RDD is made.

**This is perfect when working with Dataset or RDD but not really for Dataframe**. For your use case and for Dataframe, I would recommend just adding a column and use columns objects to do what you want.

```scala
// Using expr
df.withColumn("TOTAL", expr("A+B+C"))
// Using columns
df.withColumn("TOTAL", col("A")+col("B")+col("C"))
// Using dynamic selection of all columns
df.withColumn("TOTAL", df.colums.map(col).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2))
```

In that case, you'll be very interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360540/spark-sum-of-row-values).
UDF is also a good solution and is better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434647/process-all-columns-the-entire-row-in-a-spark-udf).

If you don't want to keep source columns, you can replace `.withColumn(name, value)` with `.select(value.alias(name))`